# Input field auto complete search select name and store the id in input box laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, laravel, typehead

Using laravel and jquery for `input` field `autocomplete`. I need to select name and store the `id` of that user in `input` field.

```
 <input id="show-user" type="text" class="typeahead form-control" name="student_code" value="{{ old('student_code') }}" placeholder="Student Code" required>
```

Here is javascript code

```
var path = "{{ url('library/issue-books/autocomplete/') }}";
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
            return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
```

Controller code for ptah

```
$data = User::where("name","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")->get();
    return response()->json($data);
```

Now my problem is when I select name, need to send student code in `request`. `Student_code integer` column.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the input value to your route:

```
return $.get(path + $('#show-user').val(), {}, function (data) {
    return process(data);
});
```

In this way you should have this route syntax:

```
/library/issue-books/autocomplete/{$query}
```

But you can pass just a query string also:

```
return $.get(path + '?query=' + $('#show-user').val(), {}, function (data) {
    return process(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response:). This code is also sent user name like before, I need the id of the selected user